# How do I align text in top left corner of div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

Trying to align a number in the top left corner of a div square. Justify content is moving it correctly, but I can't seem to get align-items OR align-self to move the text vertically.

Thoughts? And thank you for your help

```
body{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

.grid {
   margin: o;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 45px);
   gap: 10px;
   list-style-type: none;


}

.cell {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: left;
   align-self: flex-start;

   background-color: grey;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Can you share (a minimal example of) your markup as well?

Comment: Please use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a [mre] of your attempts. You may wish to read [ask] for more tips on asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll update my answer with more specific code samples, once you've shared your markup)

### Option #1 - Absolute Positioning

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25rem;
  left: 0.25rem;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-left">[123]</div>
</div>
```

### Option #2 - Flex Layout

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: baseline;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.top-left {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-left">[123]</div>
</div>
```

### Option #3 - Grid Layout

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.top-left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}

.cell {
  border: 2px dashed yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-left">[123]</div>
  <div class="cell">[CELL]</div>
  <div class="cell">[CELL]</div>
  <div class="cell">[CELL]</div>
  <div class="cell">[CELL]</div>
  <div class="cell">[CELL]</div>
  <div class="cell">[CELL]</div>
  <div class="cell">[CELL]</div>
  <div class="cell">[CELL]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m making a grid and filling it with cells I create dynamically. Sorry I’m still learning how to format things in stack overflow… 
     <div class="grid"></div>
     for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        let cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.classList.add("cell");
        let num = document.createElement("p");
        num.textContent = counter + i;
    
        cell.appendChild(num);
        grid.appendChild(cell);
      }

Answer (score 0):

To vertically align the text in the top left corner of your `.cell` divs, you can use the `align-items: flex-start` property on the `.cell` class like this:

```
.cell {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: left;
   align-items: flex-start;
   background-color: grey;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: black;
}
```

This will vertically align the content of the .cell divs along the top edge of the divs.